# Select rows ignoring narrow times

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `[EventLog]` that contains reads data, recorded by a card reader that controls a gate. However, the same card code `[epc]` can be read multiple times, during card holder holding for some time near the reader.

I want to show reads for the same code, on the same reader, but ignoring reads for 2 minutes for example.

Example: EventLog

```
ID  EPC ReaderID    LogTime
1   1234    1   2016-04-15 12:33:55
2   1234    1   2016-04-15 12:34:05
3   1234    1   2016-04-15 12:34:10
4   4321    2   2016-04-15 12:34:12
5   4321    2   2016-04-15 12:34:14
```

Desired result:

```
ID  EPC ReaderID    LogTime
1   1234    1   2016-04-15 12:33:55
4   4321    2   2016-04-15 12:34:12
```

What I am using now is the windows function `LAG` to determine the difference in minutes between each read and it previous one:

```
SELECT EPC, ReaderName, PersonName, LogTime
FROM (
SELECT EPC, ReaderName, PersonName, LogTime,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LAG(LogTime) OVER (PARTITION BY EPC, ReaderID ORDER BY LogTime), LogTime) diff_prev
FROM EventLog l
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Person p ON p.EPC = l.EPC
    INNER JOIN Reader r ON r.ID = l.ReaderID
) tbl
WHERE diff_prev IS NULL OR diff_prev >= @ignoreMinutes
ORDER BY LogTime
```

Where `@ignoreMinutes` is a parameter that specifies how many minutes to ignore the same read.

But this solution is not correct in cases where the card is read once per second, for 3 hours. for Example:

```
ID  EPC ReaderID    LogTime     diff_prev
1   1234    1   2016-04-15 12:33:55     NULL
2   1234    1   2016-04-15 12:34:05     0
3   1234    1   2016-04-15 12:34:10     0
4   1234    1   2016-04-15 12:34:32     0
5   1234    1   2016-04-15 12:34:54     0
6   1234    1   2016-04-15 12:35:14     0
7   1234    1   2016-04-15 12:35:34     0
8   1234    1   2016-04-15 12:35:54     0
9   1234    1   2016-04-15 12:36:04     0
10  1234    1   2016-04-15 12:36:15     0
11   4321   2   2016-04-15 12:44:12     NULL
12   4321   2   2016-04-15 12:44:14     0
```

As you see, my solution when executed with `@ignoreMinutes = 1`, will result in only 2 rows selected `ID = 1, 11` since the rest are all `diff_prev = 0`. But the correct result set should be `ID = 1, 6, 10, 11`

Can you help? Thanks!

Comment: @aucuparia Thank you for your interest! Yes it certainly can be done using cursor, but not good.

Comment: When I execute your subquery against your second example, it gives `diff_prev = 1` for IDs 2, 6, and 9, as `DATEDIFF(minute...` counts minute boundaries not 60-second periods.  So 12:35:01 is a minute after 12:34:59 as far as `DATEDIFF` is concerned.  I'm a bit puzzled as to how you got the results you posted?

Comment: (`FIRST_VALUE` doesn't help at all in fact - deleted my previous comment!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a 'candidate' solution I came up with. At least it works correctly on your last example, returning records 1, 6, 10, 11.

```
DECLARE @intervalSeconds INT
SET @intervalSeconds = 60;

WITH EL AS
(
    -- Select first record for each EPC, this is the baseline for recursion
    SELECT
        ID,
        EPC,
        LogTime
    FROM EventLog
    WHERE LogTime = (SELECT MIN(LogTime) FROM EventLog IEL WHERE IEL.EPC = EventLog.EPC)
    -- Add following events
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        ID,
        EPC,
        LogTime
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            NextEvent.ID,
            NextEvent.EPC,
            NextEvent.LogTime,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NextEvent.EPC ORDER BY NextEvent.LogTime) eventNumber
        FROM EventLog NextEvent
        JOIN
        (
            SELECT 
                ID,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EPC ORDER BY LogTime DESC) eventNumber, -- Reverse numbering to get last row by readNumber = 1
                EPC,
                LogTime
            FROM EL -- Recursion
        ) PreviousEvent -- Here we have all already selected events wich we're interested in
            ON PreviousEvent.EPC = NextEvent.EPC
                AND PreviousEvent.eventNumber = 1 -- We need only the last one for each EPC
        WHERE DATEDIFF(SECOND, PreviousEvent.LogTime, NextEvent.LogTime) > @intervalSeconds

    ) NextCandidateEvents -- Here we have all events with desired interval offset for each EPC
    WHERE NextCandidateEvents.eventNumber = 1 -- We need only the first one for each EPC
)
SELECT * FROM EL
ORDER BY EPC, LogTime
```

Comment: It works as expected, thank you. But I cannot understand it. Can you elaborate the idea briefly? Thank you again

Comment: Briefly on example of one EPC. Let's say we start with an empty set. We take the first row and add it to the set, then start a recursion. In the recursion we (1) find all rows with date offset greater than @intervalSeconds from maximum date in the set; (2) add the first (ordered by date) of these rows into the set; (3) return to (1). Now we apply this algorithm to the table with multiple EPCs and get above query with CTE, joins, row numbering and other stuff. :) Hope it's at least a bit clearer to you now.